# The output of the site I scrape includes html elements

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to scrape the table with letter 'A' only. My code is this so far:

```py
class ChallengeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "challenge"
    allowed_domains = ["laws.bahamas.gov.bs"]
    start_urls = ["http://laws.bahamas.gov.bs/cms/en/legislation/acts.html"]
```

The problem is when I parse the page, html elements appear in the output. This is my `parse` function.

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        css_selector = ".hasTip"

        rows = response.css(css_selector)
        for row in rows:
            title = row.css(".hasTip").get()
            source_url = row.css(".hasTip").get()
            date = row.css(".hasTip").get()
            yield {
                "title": title,
                "source_url": source_url,
                "date": date,
            }
```

The out put is:

```json
[
{"title": "<div id=\"alphabet\" class=\"hasTip\" title=\"Alphabetical Selection\" rel=\"\n\t\t    Click on one of the alphabetical buttons to select all Acts commencing with that letter. The selection will 'stick' even if you navigate to another page.\">\n            <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitX\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"A\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"B\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"C\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"D\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"E\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"F\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"G\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"H\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"I\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"J\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"K\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"L\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"M\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"N\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"O\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"P\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Q\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"R\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"S\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"T\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"U\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"V\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"W\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"X\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Y\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Z\">            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pointintime\" value=\"2023-07-26 00:00:00\">\n        </div>", "source_url": "<div id=\"alphabet\" class=\"hasTip\" title=\"Alphabetical Selection\" rel=\"\n\t\t    Click on one of the alphabetical buttons to select all Acts commencing with that letter. The selection will 'stick' even if you navigate to another page.\">\n            <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitX\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"A\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"B\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"C\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"D\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"E\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"F\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"G\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"H\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"I\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"J\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"K\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"L\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"M\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"N\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"O\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"P\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Q\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"R\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"S\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"T\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"U\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"V\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"W\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"X\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Y\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Z\">            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pointintime\" value=\"2023-07-26 00:00:00\">\n        </div>", "date": "<div id=\"alphabet\" class=\"hasTip\" title=\"Alphabetical Selection\" rel=\"\n\t\t    Click on one of the alphabetical buttons to select all Acts commencing with that letter. The selection will 'stick' even if you navigate to another page.\">\n            <input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitX\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"A\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"B\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"C\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"D\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"E\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"F\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"G\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"H\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"I\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"J\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"K\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"L\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"M\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"N\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"O\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"P\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Q\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"R\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"S\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"T\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"U\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"V\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"W\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"X\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Y\"><input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit4\" name=\"submit4\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Z\">            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pointintime\" value=\"2023-07-26 00:00:00\">\n        </div>"},
{"title": "<td class=\"hasTip minColumn hidden-phone\" title=\"Notes Relating to this Statute\" rel=\"\n
]
```

What I need to do is to add `http://laws.bahamas.gov.bs` to the pdf file urls and clean up the data that I've scraped. What else do I need to do to get what I need?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are getting more than you'd like to with your CSS selector. The `.hasTip` is a class that is present in every cell of the table. So each row will be a different value.

I think you could do something like this to get all the rows of interest:

```py
response.css("table.table > tbody > tr.row0")
```

Then, while iterating through every row, you could get the information you need like this:

```py
title = row.css("a::text").get()
source_url = row.css("a").attrib["href"]
...
```

Hope this helps!